# Как перехватить сетевые пакеты?

Tags: сеть

Хочу найти способ и понять как можно перехватить сетевые пакеты. Подскажите, какую информацию и ресурсы можно изучить. Интересуюсь в целях саморазвития.

Comment: Просто поставить Wireshark?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на сайт Владимирович, 
пожалуйста ознакомьтесь с сылками: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic